# text being cut in pygame

Tags: python, pygame

I seem to have problems with displaying text on the screen
The code draws text on the screen but half 'S' of 'Score' gets cut for reason.
However, if I change screen.blit(text, self.score_rect, self.score_rect) to screen.blit(text, self.score_rect), it works fine. I would like to know why is this happening and how can I fix this.

Thanks.

Here's the code:

```
class Score(object):
def __init__(self, bg, score=100):
    self.score = score
    self.score_rect = pygame.Rect((10,0), (200,50))
    self.bg = bg

def update(self):
    screen = pygame.display.get_surface() 

    font = pygame.font.Font('data/OpenSans-Light.ttf', 30)
    WHITE = (255, 255, 255)
    BG = (10, 10, 10)

    score = "Score: " + str(self.score)
    text = font.render(score, True, WHITE, BG)
    text.set_colorkey(BG)

    screen.blit(
    self.bg, 
    self.score_rect,
    self.score_rect)

    screen.blit(text, 
    self.score_rect, 
    self.score_rect)


def main():
    pygame.init()

    #initialize pygame
    pygame.init()
    screen = pygame.display.set_mode((640, 480))
    pygame.display.set_caption('Score Window')

    #initialize background
    bg = pygame.Surface((screen.get_size())).convert()
    bg.fill((30, 30, 30))
    screen.blit(bg, (0, 0))

    #initialize scoreboard
    score_board = Score(bg)

    while True:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == QUIT:
                exit(0)

        score_board.update()
        pygame.display.flip()
```

Comment: In simpler terms of what @jsbueno was saying: blit takes two arguments, surface and position, which positions is a tuple, not two separate points outside of tuple, so what that means is `screen.blit(bg, 5, 5)` will not work, but `screen.blit(bg, (5, 5)` will work and will draw the bg to the screen starting at pixel point (5,5). So when you use `screen.blit(text, self.score_rect, self.score_rect) you are cutting the surface short, but using `self.score_rect` it will give the x, y coordinates and the width, and height an example would look like `screen.blit(text, (0,0,20,10)` I hope this helps!

Comment: @DuhProgrammer13 it surely did, thank you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well - it looks like the third parameter on the call do `blit`, where you repeat the  core_rect` parameter is designed exactly to do that: it selects a rectangular area on the
source image (in this case your rendered text) to be pasted in the destination (in this case, the screen).

Text in Pygame is rendered with nice margins, you should not need the source-crop parameter at all - and if you thinbk ou do, you should pass it a suitable set of coordinates, relevant inside the rendered text, not therectangle with the destination coordinates on the screen.

From http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html#pygame.Surface.blit:

> blit() draw one image onto another blit(source, dest, area=None,
>   special_flags = 0) -> Rect Draws a source Surface onto this Surface.
>   The draw can be positioned with the dest argument. Dest can either be
>   pair of coordinates representing the upper left corner of the source.
>   A Rect can also be passed as the destination and the topleft corner of
>   the rectangle will be used as the position for the blit. The size of
>   the destination rectangle does not effect the blit.
>
> An optional area rectangle can be passed as well. This represents a
>   smaller portion of the source Surface to draw.
>   ...